# How to create dynamic select options with different input fields?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

If option 1 is selected, two buttons should appear. If option 2 is selected, one button and one input field should appear. If option 3 is selected, two input fields should appear. With this code, nothing is changing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function vidType() {
      var s1 = document.getElementById(select1);
      if (s1.value == "Video File") {
        var btn1 = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        var t = document.createTextNode("UPLOAD IMAGE");
        btn1.appendChild(t);
        var btn2 = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        var t2 = document.createTextNode("UPLOAD VIDEO");
        btn2.appendChild(t2);
      } else if (s1.value == "Youtube Video") {
        var btn3 = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        var t3 = document.createTextNode("UPLOAD IMAGE");
        btn3.appendChild(t3);
        var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
        x.setAttribute("type", "text");
        x.setAttribute("value", "Paste URL here");
        document.body.appendChild(x);
      } else if (s1.value == "Other Video") {
        var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
        y.setAttribute("type", "text");
        y.setAttribute("value", "Paste URL of the Video");
        document.body.appendChild(y);
        var z = document.createElement("INPUT");
        z.setAttribute("type", "text");
        z.setAttribute("value", "Paste thumbnail URL here");
        document.body.appendChild(z);
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  Choose Video Type:
  <select id="select1" name="select1" onchange="vidType()">
    <option value="Select Type">Select Video Type</option>
    <option value="Video File">Video File</option>
    <option value="Youtube Video">Youtube Video</option>
    <option value="Other Video">Other Video</option>
    </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you open your console (F12), you'll see why it isn't working.

Comment: Hint: `select1` needs to be in quotes ...

Comment: thanks for pointing it out...

Comment: but now every time I select an option it's showing one input field but when I'm selecting another option or that option it's generating one more time the same thing.... same thing is generating until I refresh the page...

Comment: Well, do you ever remove any of the added elements ?

Comment: it's generating the same field many times... like while I'm selecting option 1 it's showing only the input field not button and after that without reloading the page if I select option 2 it's showing the input field for option 2 beside the field for option 1...

Comment: Well, yes, it generates elements everytime the value changes, that's what you've told it to do.

Comment: how to solve it.. like I want it to work in such manner that after I change the value it should only generate the fields that are in that option and removes previous elements...

Comment: You'd have to remove the elements you've added previously

Answer (score 1):

Only problem seems to be with this line

```
var s1 = document.getElementById(select1);
```

If you change it to

```
var s1 = document.getElementById("select1");
```

it will work.
The reason it doesn't work is element id's should be passed as strings, i.e. enclosed in single or double quotes.